MITRE ATT&CK Framework with Suricata
I've recently started working with suricata and don't have much experience with it yet. What I'm looking for is, If there's a way to configure suricata to be able to detect various MITRE ATT&CK techniques related to network attacks ?
I don't have much knowledge about this. I do know about ET Open and ET Pro ruleset but after reading certain article I get to know that ET Open doesn't includes many attack rules and currently not able to afford for PRO. I do know about lua and how it's been used with Suricata but have no clue how it can be used here. Either I collect rules which can a large number or make rules myself based on the various techniques. Can please anyone help me with this ?
